# ¿Cómo puedo saber cuando termina el TTS?

Tags: android, android-intent, vistas

Tengo una aplicación que lee el contenido que hay en un textview y quiero que cuando termine de leerlo se lance otra vista... otro activity

```
    public void TextToSpeechFunction() {
    String textholder = textView.getText().toString();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        textToSpeech.speak(textholder, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    else
        textToSpeech.speak(textholder, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    textToSpeech.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        TextToSpeechFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré un fragmento de [código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658376/how-to-know-when-tts-is-finished) donde podes saber cuándo se terminó el texto. En el método onDone colocas la actividad que querés llamar.

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                // Llamar a otra actividad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Inicializacion erronea!");
    }
}
```